# Encryption of URL in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I encrypt the URL while navigating in asp.net 3.5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're attempting to pass sensitive data through the URL, then you are taking the wrong approach.

Perhaps a better alternative would be to use a Session State.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean URL encoding, see here:

[HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-EN/library/zttxte6w%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Else, please provide more details...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you wnat to encrypt an URL. I think you can do that, or it makes sense to do it.

I think you want to encode the query strings of the URL.

Suppose your URL is, you can URL encode your querystring as -

```
http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?data1=value1&date2=value2&date3=HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode("my new value3")
```

To read it back you can use [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx).